# In VC++, how to access text continuously from console window and print it in a CListBox?

Tags: visual-c++

In VC++, how to access text continuously from console window and print it in a CListBox? Infact I have a MFC program which calls other FORTRAN exe. The output of the FORTRAN exe comes in the console window. I need to print it in a CListBox continuously. I can print it in a file and can print it at one shot. But that is not my purpose. I need continuous feed. Can any one help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

_popen may work for you, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft article should get you most of the way there:
[How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351)